# Loading weights after a training run in KERAS not recognising the highest level of accuracy achieved in previous run

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, loading

I conduct a training run and finish with the following output from a KERAS NN model. I have added a confusion matrix output for model quality

...

Epoch 09998: val_acc did not improve from 0.83780
Epoch 9999/10000
12232/12232 [==============================] - 1s 49us/step - loss: 0.2656 - acc: 0.9133 - val_loss: 0.6134 - val_acc: 0.8051

Epoch 09999: val_acc did not improve from 0.83780
Epoch 10000/10000
12232/12232 [==============================] - 1s 48us/step - loss: 0.2655 - acc: 0.9124 - val_loss: 0.5918 - val_acc: 0.8283

Epoch 10000: val_acc did not improve from 0.83780
3058/3058 [==============================] - 0s 46us/step

acc: 82.83%
Model Quality
Tn: 806  Tp: 1727  Fp: 262  Fn: 263
Precision: 0.8683 Recall: 0.8678 Accuracy 0.8283 F score 0.8681

I then make a change to a hyper parameter and reload everything and recompile using the following code

```
# prep checkpointing
model_file = output_file.rsplit('.',1)[0] + '_model.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_file, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model.load_weights(model_file) # - commented out first time thru, reload second time thru

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=l_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(model_test_X, model_test_y),
          batch_size = batch_s, epochs=num_epochs, 
          callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)
```

Upon re-starting I would expect the best accuracy to be as it was above. In this instance val_acc = 0.83780

However, after the first two epochs I get this output:

Epoch 1/10000
12232/12232 [==============================] - 1s 99us/step - loss: 0.2747 - acc: 0.9097 - val_loss: 0.6191 - val_acc: 0.8143

Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.81426, saving model to Data_model.h5

Epoch 2/10000
12232/12232 [==============================] - 1s 42us/step - loss: 0.2591 - acc: 0.9168 - val_loss: 0.6367 - val_acc: 0.8322

Epoch 00002: val_acc improved from 0.81426 to 0.83224, saving model to Data_model.h5

Epoch 3/10000
12232/12232 [==============================] - 1s 44us/step - loss: 0.2699 - acc: 0.9140 - val_loss: 0.6157 - val_acc: 0.8313

Epoch 00003: val_acc did not improve from 0.83224
......

While I understand the model may start from a different place, my assumption was that the best level of accuracy (val_acc) would have been carried over from the previous run.

My question is am i missing something?

Comment: You restart the training so the `ModelCheckpoint` is also reinitialized. I am not sure why this is a problem?

Comment: @Wilmar, are you suggestion that I do not reinitialise the checkpoint after the first time through. I will try it

Comment: No everytime you start a new training process the checkpoint also (re) starts. It doesn't bring the level of accuracy to the next training phase. That isn't useful at all as you might have changed the entire model.

Answer (score 1):

About `ModelCheckpoint`, as *Wilmar van Ommeren* already wrote in the comment, every time you call this class it is reinitialized the process of searching best result, because it's a class and you assign an instance of it to a variable called **checkpoint**.

Fortunately **Keras** is an open source project meaning that you can read how the class [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a8606fd45b760cce3e65727e9d62cae796c45930/keras/callbacks.py#L1160) is written and it turns out that, every time you make an instance of this class, the special method [`__init__`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a8606fd45b760cce3e65727e9d62cae796c45930/keras/callbacks.py#L1260-L1344) always initialize a **public** variable called **best** to Infinity or -Infinity, which depends on the argument you pass to the parameter **mode** inside the constructor of the class.

So every time you repeat the training of the model, the last result is always overwritten by the first training process of the new training session because the variable **best** is set to an *Infinity value*, losing all the effort from the previous training session.

To make your training sessions continuing the previous ones you just have to save the best result from the previous training session, which you can do it by taking the [History](https://keras.io/guides/training_with_built_in_methods/#api-overview-a-first-endtoend-example) object from the `model.fit()` method, and save it into a variable or file. Then, when you have to continue the training of the model, before you call the `model.fit()` method specify the best result from the previous training into the variable checkpoint, in your case is the **val_acc**. In summary, this is the "pseudocode" you need to solve your problem with `ModelCheckpoint`:

```py
# Previous training...
# Save the best result to a variable or in a file
# Load the best result into a variable
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_file, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True,mode='max')
checkpoint.best = best_accuracy_from_previous_training_session
# Repeat the training...
```

Another thing I want to point out is the `compile` method. There is nothing wrong on what you pass as arguments to the method, but recently I have found the following two issues that claims it is necessary to specify the right metrics to the method for saving the right information:

1. [Keras giving low accuracy after loading model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541824/keras-giving-low-accuracy-after-loading-model)
2. [Accuracy is lost after save/load](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42459)

Although you save and load only the **weights** of the model, it seems it is better to specify which metric you use based on the loss function. Even tho passing `'accuracy'` as a parameter it's ok because Keras chooses the right metric but sometimes might not do it in the right way.

So all you have to do is to change the string `'accuracy'` to `'binary_accuracy'` in **metrics**.